# Parsing spreadsheet syntax

Tags: java, regex, spreadsheet

I'm working on a basic spreadsheet editor (all written from scratch) with my Java class. I was tasked with writing the function package (to analyse the content of a cell and output the calculated result).
Currently I can parse an expression such as `1*(2+3)^4-5%6` by converting it to RPN and then calculating the result. Now I'm working on adding cell names to that expression. What I would like the cell name parser to do is directly replace the cell names by their numeric values, but I'm having a hard time. I've managed to find a way to use regex with one cell (inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073892/3165024), but I don't know how to make it work with multiple cell names in the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a note: Using Regex for this approach is not a correct way. Simple references like A1 can be successfully replaced by calculated 
values from referenced cells, but your task can become much more difficult when you attempt to parse more complex expressions such as 
cross-sheet references (=Sheet2!A1, ='My sheet'!A1), 3d references (=Sheet1:Sheet3!A1), references in R1C1 style(=R[-1]C3), defined names references(=name), etc.
Replacing cell references for calculated values will disallow you to calculate built-in functions like ROW(A2) (the result is 2), 
which expects reference argument instead of a cell value.

I think your RPN form should be enlarged to include items for simple references, 3d references, etc.
The simplest way to create a parser for Excel-like expressions  is the use of compiler generators. Have a look at, for example, "The Compiler Generator Coco/R"(http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Research/Projects/Coco/), it has a version for java.